# NextJS - Supabase RLS Failing

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, supabase, row-level-security

I have the following data model:[image: data model screenshot]

I want to run the following query inside my `getServerSideProps` function:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('user_profile').select(`
        subscription ( status )
    `)
    .eq('user_id', session.user.id);
```

My RLS is configured with the following expressions:

*user_profile*: `auth.uid() = user_id`

*stripe_customer*: `auth.uid() = user_id`

*subscription*:

```
(auth.uid() = ( SELECT stripe_customer.user_id
   FROM stripe_customer
  WHERE (stripe_customer.id = subscription.stripe_customer_id)))
```

This setup doesn't return any results when run from within NextJS. If I disable RLS for `subscription` table then I get results as expected. What's wrong with my RLS rule?

**Edit:**

I've tried to modify the RLS policy for the `subscription` table to both of these expression:

1. `(auth.uid() <> NULL::uuid)`
2. `(auth.uid() = NULL::uuid)`

In both situations, no record get's returned. How is that possible?

Comment: `= NULL` and `<> NULL` will never match. You'd want `auth.uid() IS NULL` and `auth.uid() IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Does `SELECT stripe_customer.user_id FROM stripe_customer WHERE stripe_customer.id = $1` return the expected value when you run it as the respective user with same example `stripe_customer_id` value? Notice that the `stripe_customer` RLS policies apply to this query as well

Comment: This normally happens when the user you are trying to make the request as isn't logged in or you are trying to use `@supabase/supabase-js` directly inside of server side code. You should use `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs` when working with frameworks like NextJS.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Troubleshooting via the suggested steps made me realise that I was missing a FK constraint in the subscription.stripe_customer_id column, and that resulted in the evaluation of the auth.uid() not matching what was stored in the record.